# Adding list of URLs to an array?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using [MHVideoPhotoGallery](https://github.com/mariohahn/MHVideoPhotoGallery) to create gallery's of images that are stored on my website. The current way to add images (as shown in the example on Github) is

```
    MHGalleryItem *photo1 = [MHGalleryItem.alloc initWithURL:@"*ENTER IMAGE URL HERE*"
                                            galleryType:MHGalleryTypeImage];
    MHGalleryItem *photo2 = [MHGalleryItem.alloc initWithURL:@"*ENTER IMAGE URL HERE*"
                                            galleryType:MHGalleryTypeImage];
    MHGalleryItem *photo3 = [MHGalleryItem.alloc initWithURL:@"*ENTER IMAGE URL HERE*"
                                            galleryType:MHGalleryTypeImage];

    self.galleryDataSource = @[@[photo1,photo2,photo3]];
```

But I want to add hundreds of images and this is not the most ideal way to do it. What would be an easier way for me to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at the foundation docs for NSMutableArray, which lets you add the MHGalleryItem objects one at a time using `addObject:`. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Where do your 100s of URLs come from?

Comment: FYI - please don't use property syntax when calling methods like `alloc`.

Comment: Thank you! the URLs are all images on my site. Named in image_1.jpg format. And okay, I will fix the property syntax, that's just how it was in the example code!

Comment: So do you plan to hardcode all of the URLs in your app or do you plan to obtain the list of URLs dynamically from your server?

Comment: The URLs will not change so I planned on hardcoding them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to start with a list of the URLs. What I would do is put this in a text file in my bundle. In code, when the app runs, I would open the text file (as an NSString) and split it into an NSArray. Now I've got an NSArray of the URLs. I would then cycle through the NSArray. So now we're inside a loop. For each item the array, I would initialize the MHGalleryItem and then add it to a previously created NSMutableArray with `addObject:`. Thus we have a two or three-line loop which is repeated, running through all the URLs.

The following is pseudo-code and untested (so it might contain errors), but it should give the general idea of the structure I'm suggesting:

```
NSMutableArray* temp = [NSMutableArray new];
NSString* s =
    [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"urls" ofType:@"txt"]
                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray* urls = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
for (NSString* url in urls) {
    MHGalleryItem *item = [[MHGalleryItem alloc] initWithURL:url
                                        galleryType:MHGalleryTypeImage];
    [temp addObject:item];
}
self.galleryDataSource = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop. If you're putting numbers at the end of your variable names, you need a loop and/or an array.

```
NSMutableArray * photos = [NSMutableArray new];
NSArray * photoPaths = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistContainingPhotoPaths];
for( NSString * path in photoPaths ){
    NSURL * photoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    MHGalleryItem * photo = [[MHGalleryItem alloc] initWithURL:photoURL
                                                   galleryType:MHGalleryTypeImage];
    [photos addObject:photo];
}
```

And don't use dot syntax for `alloc`, or your code will burst into flames.

Answer (score 0):

Use a naming protocol on your website such as:

www.mywebsite.com/appImageGallery/insertImageNumber

And replace the insertImageNumber with the number of you image. Then add this for loop to get all of the images and add them to the array.

```
NSMutableArray *mutableGalleryDataSource = [self.galleryDataSource mutableCopy]
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfImagesOnWebsite; i++){    //replace numberOfImagesOnWebsite with the number of images on your website.

    MHGalleryItem *newItem = [MHGalleryItem.alloc initWithURL:[@"www.mywebsite.com/appImageGallery/" stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i", i]] galleryType:MHGalleryTypeImage];

    [mutableGalleryDataSource addObject:newItem];
}
self.galleryDataSource = mutableGalleryDataSource;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also an `-addObjectsFromArray` method on `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: This answer would be far more useful if you expanded it a bit. Show how it applies to the question.